# Merge routes in servicestack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a Dto like this:

```
[Route("/clients/", HttpMethods.Post)]
[Route("/clients/{Dummy}", HttpMethods.Post)]
public class ClientPostDto : IReturnVoid
{
    public string Dummy { get; set; }
}
```

And the post method in my service:

```
public class ClientService : Service
{
    public void Post(ClientPostDto request)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Is it possible to merge these two routings?

So the following two POST request are handled by the same Method in my Service:

```
localhost:12345/clients/
localhost:12345/clients/CLIENT_IDENTIFIER
```

I won't need the Dummy property at all, because the clients are stored in a list with the full path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the magic `{ignore}` literal instead, i.e. if you want to specify a wildcard without needing to specify an existing property, e.g:

```
[Route("/clients/{ignore}", "POST")]
public class ClientPostDto : IReturnVoid {}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should just work.  But you should keep the dummy variable so you know what has been requested perhaps retitled to ClientIdentifier.